# Required permission to create directory

Tags: files, permissions, filesystems

I'm trying to create a sub directory under existing directory tree. I want to know if only the permissions of directory where I'll be creating my sub directory matter or the parent directories will also have some effect on the permission to create the directory?

I'll be doing this programmatically, so I need to be sure that I have covered a wide range of scenarios.

Comment: Why don't you try it? Create different directories with different permissions and see how they effect your ability to create a sub-directory. Should take you a few minutes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, they matter. To create a directory, you need to be able to write to its parent directory. Creating a directory is just like creating a file (after all, [everything is a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file)) so you need write access to the parent. In addition, you need to be able to get to the parent directory which means you need execute access to all directories in the tree:

```
$ sudo tree -pgu 
.
└── [drwxr-xr-x terdon terdon]  dir1
    └── [drwx------ bob      bob     ]  dir2
        └── [drwxr-xr-x terdon terdon]  dir3
```

In the example above, `dir2` is owned by `bob`. This means I cannot `cd` into it, and I can't `cd` into its subdirectory `dir3` either:

```
$ cd dir1/dir2/
bash: cd: dir1/dir2/: Permission denied
$ cd dir1/dir2/dir3
bash: cd: dir1/dir2/dir3: Permission denied
```

If I give myself execute access to `dir2`, I will be able to move to both `dir2` and `dir2/dir3`, but I still won't have the right to create files/directories in `dir2`:

```
$ sudo tree -pgu 
.
└── [drwxr-xr-x terdon terdon]  dir1
    └── [drwx--x--x bob      bob     ]  dir2
        └── [drwxr-xr-x terdon terdon]  dir3

$ cd dir1/dir2/
$ ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
$ touch file
touch: cannot touch 'file': Permission denied
```

As you can see above, while I can move into the directory, I can't list its contents because I don't have read access to it and I can't create anything there because I don't have write access.

So, to be able to create a new file or directory inside a directory you need:

- Execute permissions on every parent directory of your target directory.
- Execute and write permissions for the target directory.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. I could not figure out that execute permission is required for navigation. Thanks.